# List View e Layout normal numa Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Olá, estou querendo que uma tela tenha um botão e, abaixo desse botão, uma lista com vários itens. Mas acontece que os botões estão multiplicados.

Veja:

activity.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nova"
        android:onClick="nova"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/nova" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity.java

```java
package com.educin.leonardo.nomes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TarefasActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] de = {"nome"};
        int[] para = {R.id.nome};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listarNomes(), R.layout.activity, de, para);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> nomes;

    private List<Map<String, Object>> listarNomes() {
        nmes = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("nome", "Leonardo");
        nomes.add(item);

        item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("nome", "Leo");
        nomes.add(item);

        return nome;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Map<String, Object> map = nomes.get(position);

        String nome = (String) map.get("nome");

        Toast.makeText(this, nome, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void nova(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.nova) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, NovaNovaActivity.class));
        }
    }

}
```

Explicando melhor: São formadas duas linhas e um botão em cada linha. Mas eu gostaria apenas de um botão no topo da Activity.

Como resolver?

Comment: Só de bater o olho, eu vejo quatro duas coisas estranhas. Primeiro essa linha: `nmes = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();` - A variável `nmes` não existe, deveria ser `nomes`. No final do método o `return nome;` também deveria ser `return nomes;`. Já no método `onItemClick`, aquele cast para `String` me parece totalmente desnecessário. Além disso, porque que `nomes` é um `List<Map<String, Object>>` ao invés de um `List<String>`, uma vez que cada `Map` só tem uma única chave `"nome"` e o valor é sempre do tipo `String`?

Comment: Isso é pq eu mudei o nome das variáveis quando fui postar no Stack, e não conferi se o nome delas estavam certas, pois o ponto do tópico é outro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve setar um layout para sua `Activity` que tenha o botão e o `ListView`. Nesse caso você só está configurando o **layout** dos itens do `ListView` com todo o conteúdo da `Activity`.

Um layout simples da `Activity`, reaproveitando o seu, seria:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nova"
        android:onClick="nova"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/nova" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list" <!-- Obrigatorio no caso da ListActivity -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Agora para cada item da lista você pode usar o próprio layout padrão [`android.r.layout.simple_list_item_1`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml), que possui apenas um `TextView`:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listarNomes(), android.r.layout.simple_list_item_1, de, android.R.id.text1);
```

E não esqueça de chamar o `setContentView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    // restante do seu código...
}
```